# How to store client names that've accessed wifi via captive portal?

Tags: wifi, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I'd like to setup a captive portal for an open wifi network, where users can access the internet by only entering their first names.

The aim of which is to build a list of first names currently connected to the network. Ideally this setup would remember MAC addresses and be able to greet returning clients (on an external display) the next time they automatically access the wifi network. (Can clients access the internet without having to re-login through captive portal?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an SQl database and store in it the first name and the MAC address of the client.
When the client log again you juste have to make a simple SQL request to find the name associated to the MAC address